# How save model after pass as param ? or get as function ? core data

Tags: swift, core-data

Problem 1.

I have a tableViewController

```
var stocksResults: [Any] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    loadList()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toTrade" {
        let indexPath = self.stockTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let vc = segue.destination as! StockTradeController
        vc.stockResults = stocksResults[indexPath!.row] as AnyObject
    }    
}

func loadList() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Stocks")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {stocksResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)}
    catch {print("Error")}

   stockTableView.reloadData()
}
```

code is simple, i show data from CoreData entity `Stocks` and when iIclick on row i will pass model to another viewController as

```
vc.stockResults = stocksResults[indexPath!.row] as AnyObject
```

in other view i can modify this model

```
(stockResults as AnyObject).setValue(345, forKey: "own")
```

And the question is how can i save model after modification ?

---

Problem 2

I created class

```
class UserAccount {
    
    func getData() -> Array<Any> {
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Account")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do {
            let accountUser = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return accountUser
        }
        catch {print("Error")}
        
        return []
        
    }
}
```

i can get and change model in any VC

```
(UserAccount().getData()[0] as AnyObject).setValue(433, forKey: "cash")
```

I can run this function from any VC and the same question how can i save changes ? Should i pass context in both cases some how ? or what is the best way ?

Comment: a) Why are you casting your model object at all instead of using the `Stocks` class directly? If you don't cast you can do `stockResults.own = 345` instead. b) Once you have updated the object you can just call save on your NSManagedObjectContext c) You are only supposed to ask one question

Comment: i am just learning so how can i use Stocks class directly ? Do i need to create ```Stocks``` ? b) idk how use ```NSManagedObjectContext```  any chance for small example ? c) i am sorry :(

Comment: But you are already using NSManagedObjectContext in `loadList`, it's your `context` variable. The Stocks class is created for you by the compiler so you can use it directly. Anyway, see the answer below by @vadian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the standard implementation of the Core Data stack in `AppDelegate` (it seems so) you can save the context from everywhere with

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

---

There are many bad practices in your code.

- Declare the data source array with the specific entity type

  ```
    var stocksResults: [Stocks] = []
  ```

  This avoids the ugly type cast to `AnyObject`
- In the second view controller you are dealing with a **single** object so declare

  ```
   var stock : Stocks!
  ```

  and assign

  ```
   vc.stock = stocksResults[indexPath!.row]
  ```
- By the way it's recommended to name also an entity in singular form (`Stock`)
- In `loadList()` specify the fetch request and print the **real** error

  ```
  func loadList() {
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

      let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Stocks>(entityName: "Stocks")
      fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

      do {
         stocksResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
      } catch {print(error)}

      stockTableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- Rather than KVC use dot notation

  ```
  stock.own = 345
  ```
- In `UserAccount` do the same: Take advantage of the generic fetch request and return the Entity

  ```
  func getData() -> Array<Account> { ...
  ```